# Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.open]" nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)

Tags: exception, extjs

I spent 2 days trying to figure out this error and would like to share the resolution

Problem:
  I am trying to reconfigure extjs grid panel at runtime with different datastore

Code with Error:

```
var el = Ext.getCmp('DummyGrid');
  el.reconfigure(SLADataStore, SLAColumnModel);
  el.load();
```

Error:
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.open]" nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)" location: "JS frame :: http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.1/adapter/ext/ext-base.js

code without Error:

```
var el = Ext.getCmp('DummyGrid');
el.reconfigure(SLADataStore, SLAColumnModel);
SLADataStore.load({
     params: {  start: 0,
                limit: 25, 
                sort: 'LevelID',
                dir: 'ASC'}
                 });
```

Reason for the error: when I try to load it should have been datastore.load() not the component.load()

Hope this post might help 2 days of their time which might be well spent on beers ;)

-Sat

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
el.getStore().load();
```